# Google not indexing video from video sitemap

Tags: sitemap, google-index, video-sitemap

I run a website serving video content. I run my own player.

[image]

I have added Google’s structured markup to the video tags.

[image]

[Here’s the link to test a page.](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cucumbertown.com%2Fseared-halibut-and-gazpacho-salsa-recipe-dish%23play)

I also have the sitemap pointing to a video sitemap xml

[image]

But for some reason Google is not picking up these pages as video

[image]

Just two of them are mapped as video of the 115 submitted.

**What could be the reason here?**

The video recipes are duplicated in another sitemap but I don’t think that’s the reason.

Note: *You'll also see it's the same with images*.

Comment: Just because you submit it, doesn't mean it will be indexed.

Comment: @JohnConde It's been around 3 months now.

Comment: I would have expected that Google would have done more by now, but I also see that your Images are low too. It may be that Google is taking it's sweet time which is really not that uncommon even for web pages.

Comment: @closetnoc The first video was up since November 2013 (9 months now) and images for almost 2 years. So I think there's more to this.

Comment: I agree that is too long. You did not mention how long you had these images and videos on your site. Like I said, I would have expected Google would have done more... may be taking it's time. But knowing it has been 9 months, clearly something is wrong. @bybe is excellent. Perhaps her insights will help.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that Google is disliking the fact that you have the videos on the sub domain `fruits.example.com` rather than the main domain.

If you take a look at Google by doing `site:http://www.example.com` and click videos your see that the only two videos to be indexed are those actually hosted on the site.

Example:

- `<loc>http://www.cucumbertown.com/vegetables-sou-recipe-dish</loc>`
- `<loc>http://fruits.cucumbertown.com/etc/vp.swf?recipe=7746</loc>`

So you should use `<loc>Embed URL not the location of the file</loc>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.   
The two videos that are indexed are in the same domain as the rest are https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:http://www.cucumbertown.com&tbm=vid 
Can you tell me a bit more on So you should use <loc>Embed URL not the location of the file</loc>  
Didn’t catch that.

Comment: Basically `<loc>URL where people visit to view the video, not the location of the video file</loc>`, I've just checked your video-sitemap.xml and it looks like you've done the required updates.